# Django template - for loop and then if statement

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have this loop:

```
<div class="product-gallery-preview order-sm-2">
                            {% for images in Artikel.productimages_set.all %}
                            {% if images.Position == 1 %}
                                <div class="product-gallery-preview-item active" id="gallery{{ images.Position }}">
                            {% else %}
                                <div class="product-gallery-preview-item" id="gallery{{ images.Position }}">
```

the problem is that all div classes are active I think because it's true for the first picture which is found.
Is it possible to go in the loop check all pictures if it is in Position 1 and just output the div box I tried to print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forloop.counter`...

```
{% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
  <div class="product-gallery-preview-item active" id="gallery{{ images.Position }}">
{% else %}
  ....
{% endif %}
```